# Is there any way to insert xml file data into cassandra?

Tags: java, xml, cassandra

IS there any way to insert xml file data into cassandra ?
say XML file having lot of data , file size- 5MB.

Is there already available utility or Do i have to write some kind JAVA parser?
FYI, I am using cassandra 2.1.
what are option i have got ?

Answer (score 2):

Either you can use `COPY...FROM` Command [Simple data importing and exporting with Cassandra](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/simple-data-importing-and-exporting-with-cassandra)

or use `Cassandra Bulk Loader` [Using the Cassandra Bulk Loader](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/using-the-cassandra-bulk-loader-updated)
.

For second one you need to do some like JAVA parser.
For large data file, I suggest you to go with Cassandra bulk loader.

Comment: I m newbie in cassandra... COPY worked for csv and txt flat file but in XML there are lot of hierarchy and i don't know how to map those hierarchy with table structure ... ANY Sugeestions

Comment: I think you you have to read XML file using JAVA and build SSTable for load into Cassandra.

Comment: Yes, i was thinking same. Thanks karmadip :)